# youtube search filter format=5 but still can't embedded to browser

Tags: youtube-api

i have a simple youtube search like this :
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q='some-value'&v=2&format=5&start-index=1&max-results=10&alt=jsonc&callback='some-function'&orderby=viewCounts&sortorder=descending);

I thought I can use format=5 to get the video that's allow embedded. However, I still getting video that said " it's restricted payback from certain sites."

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting back a video that's embeddable on certain sites, and not embeddable on others. There's more information about embed restrictions at

http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/12/understanding-playback-restrictions.html